# Is using 'perhaps' in an essay appropriate?

Tags: word-usage, formality

My teacher was criticizing me much for the informal words used in my essay today. It was blatant that she couldn't understand the half of them anyway, but she said 'perhaps' was also an informal word.
I can kind of understand her wording for this one, because apparently in essays you  need to speak without doubt or something around those lines...
So yeah, just wondering if it is appropriate for a formal essay.

> Perhaps the greatest similarity shared in the novel extract and graphic novel, is how the woman followed her will to the very end.

This is what I said. This is a comparative essay BTW.

Comment: there is nothing ''informal'' in expressing doubt

Comment: A couple of comments. First, teachers sometimes feel compelled to find fault with a student's work. I guess they figure they are not doing their jobs if they do not. Second, some beginner writers in finding their style experiment with what I call a "chatty," conversational style.. Their teachers, on the other hand, prefer a style which is more "dignified" and scholarly.For the time being, adapt your writing style to your audience of one: your teacher. When you are no longer under his or her tutelage, you are free to use a chatty style of writing. Just tailor it to the assignment at hand.

Comment: I wonder whether she's criticizing either (a) as you say, "perhaps" builds an unnecessary caveat into the writing - readers in this genre are expecting to hear what you argue and will already take it with the appropriate grains of salt, or (b) the syntax ("the greatest similarity... is") with an unnecessary comma could be made more concise ("In both the novel extract and graphic novel the woman followed her will to the end."). Without context, it's hard to give a definite answer here beyond this: "perhaps" is used plenty of times in "formal" contexts but it is also unnecessarily used.

Answer (score 2):

'Perhaps' is not an informal word. It's got a 500 year history, it's used frequently in formal writing, no dictionary marks it as 'informal'. Using it in an essay is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: ..which is also to say that it is _not_ informal. 'Perhaps' has a educated formal feel to it. An essay is exactly the time to use it, definitely not in you conversations on the playground or smoking behind the pawnshop next to the dumpster.